# Inner join of child table with parent table

Tags: sql, select, sqlite, inner-join

I have two tables, related by a foreign key. I want to select a column from the child table based on some information about a row in the parent table.

The definitions of the tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE Runs(
    id            INTEGER, 
    name          TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
    rundate       TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE Location(
    lid           INTEGER, 
    rid           INTEGER NOT NULL,
    direc         TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (lid), 
    FOREIGN KEY (rid) REFERENCES Runs(id)
);
```

I am new to SQL so I have not quite figured out how to do this. This is what I have so far (suppose I want to get the directory for run named 012114:

```
SELECT direc FROM Location INNER JOIN Runs WHERE Runs.name = '012114';
```

I've also tried

```
SELECT direc FROM Location INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Runs WHERE Name = '012114');
```

Both of these attempts lists all entries from the direc column in the Location table. I am using sqlite.

Comment: You aren't actually joining.  You'll need something like `ON runs.<some column> = location.<some column>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably missing part of the join command where you are telling sqllite how to merge the tables, so you are getting a cartesian join.

```
SELECT direc FROM Location 
  INNER JOIN Runs 
  ON location.rid = Runs.id WHERE Runs.name = '012114';
```

This should work, assuming that location.rid is the referring to the run.

Answer (score 1):

When you do a `JOIN` clause, you need to specify which columns on each table to join.

For example:

```
SELECT direc 
FROM Location 
INNER JOIN Runs ON Runs.id = Location.rid
WHERE Runs.name = '012114';
```

Without this, you can return quite unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Other way of getting the solution if you are not using the columns from Runs Table.
For Example:

```
SELECT
  direc 
FROM 
   Location loc
WHERE 
   Exists (SELECT NULL 
FROM Runs ru WHERE ru.id =  loc.rid AND ru.name = '012114')
```